# Do android games use the graphic card on a laptop?

Tags: android-x86, graphics, hardware-acceleration

I installed Android on my laptop as dual boot with indows 8.1 (I am not talking about virtualization or emulators).

I have 1 GB NVIDIA graphic card on my laptop.  So does Android use my graphic card to improvement game performance?